Is it possible to rewrite $1/(x-b)$ such that either the denominator only contains 1 term or the $x$ and the $b$ are separated in the numerator only?
I have the expression: $$\frac{1}{x-b}$$
Is there a way to rewrite this so that the x and b are either combined into one term in the denominator (and as the only term in the denominator)? Otherwise, is there a way to make sure that both the $x$ and $b$ are separated in the numerator or something of the sort? Essentially, I want to be able to factor out the x for the expression entirely.
For context, if that helps at all, this expression is inside a summation that loops through the indexes of a set of values, of which $b$ represents the value at the index $n$. I want to be able to factor out the x from this summation. $l$ is just the size of the set.
$$\sum_{n=0}^l \frac{1}{x-b_n}$$
Approximations for $\frac{1}{x-b}$ that satisfy these conditions are also welcome. Any help is appreciated.
Edit: For clarification, I want to be able to factor out the x from the term $\frac{1}{x-b}$ entirely (so it's not present in the resulting term at all). Any method to achieve this is fine (including decent approximations).
Edit 2: The function itself is arbitrary, I just need a function like $1/x$ such that there is a vertical asymptote at the specified b value. Any function that approximates this behavior well enough such as $$\frac{cos(x-b_n)}{x-b_n}$$ is also fine, but any I have tried didn't let me take out the $x$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Let $y=x-b$. $\quad$

Just out of curiosity, what to you want to do with $\sum_{n=0}^l \frac{1}{x-b_n}$ ? If it is part of an equation, I can provide a few things

@ClaudeLeibovici The equation is $$\frac{sin(c\pi x)}{c\pi} \sum_{n=0}^l \frac{1}{x-b_n}$$. c is just an arbitrary constant. Hope this helps!

@ArjunKrishnan. This is not an equation but a formula. Is there $=0$ ?

@ClaudeLeibovici Sorry, it's just the function definition. It's not equal to anything since the point of the function is for calculation with various inputs. I need the x out of the equation for effeciency.

$\frac{1}{x-b}=-(b-x)^{-1}=\frac{-1}{b}(1-\frac{x}{b})^{-1}$
If and only if $\frac{x}{b}<<1$, we can apply $(1+y)^n=1+ny$. That would give us the value to be approximately equal to $\frac{-1}{b}(1-(-1)\frac{x}{b})=\frac{-1}{b}(1+\frac{x}{b})=\frac{-1}{b}+\frac{-x}{b^2}≈\frac{-1}{b}$
Other than using binomial approximation, it's kind of impossible to remove x.

Assuming that $x$ is small compared to all $b_n$
$$\sum_{n=0}^l \frac{1}{x-b_n} \sim-\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{b_i}-x\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{b_i^2}-x^2\sum _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{b_i^2}-\cdots$$
